# SQL Server 2008 external disc back-up

Tags: sql, backup, database-backups

I have an external network back up disc mapped at Y:\ , when I try to create back up on disc Y:\ I have

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASE_NAME] TO  DISK = 'Y:\backup\backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = @BackupName, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

when I run it following error occurs

Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_backup, Line 10
Cannot open backup device 'Y:\backup\backup.bak'. Operating system error 3(Path not found.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a UNC path (e.g. `\\server\share\backup\backup.bak`). Whilst you may have the `Y` drive mapped, the user account that SQL Server is running under doesn't. And it's that "user" that is going to perform the data access.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is no folder 'backup' on drive Y:
Or your account haven't appropriate permissions to this folder.